# Connect to Oracle Database that runs on another server

Tags: oracle, proxy, tunnel

This is the scenario.

```
We Have 4 Servers (A, B, C, D). 
Server A: runs Oracle DB and listener.
Server B: can connect(see) to server A.
Server C: can connect to server B but can't connect to server A.
Server D: can connect to server C but can't connect to servers (A, B) and runs SQLPLUS on it.
```

now I wonder that is it possible to connect SQLPLUS on server D to Oracle DB that runs on Server A via Servers (B, C).

Comment: If you just want SQL*Plus, can you `ssh` from D->C, then from C->B, then `SQL*Plus` from your `ssh` session on B?  If you are looking to connect directly from D, you need server proxies for the Oracle Database running on B and C.  That's Oracle Connection Manager.  It's free with Oracle Enterprise Edition, I believe.

Comment: Configure a port forwarding on servers C and B. Choose one port number, say 8765, then forward this port on C to B, and on B to A. Configure a listener on A for this port, and connect from SQL-Plus on D to C to this port..